# Create and access Updating table within Kstreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to access stream of data "A", check some conditions against table "B" and finally update state of table "B".

```
(A,B) ====> check conditions in B ====> finally update B
```

How can I implement same logic in **kafka streams**?  From Documentation my observation is that for streaming data "A" we can use Kstreams and for updating table "B" we can use Ktable. But only operation allowed between kstreams and ktable is joins and it does not updates ktable(instead uses it only as lookup). Also it creates another new kstream(that I dont want). In short, I want to access Ktable as as updating table with reference to incoming stream, so how can we implement same in kafka streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of a `KTable` is maintained by Streams API and you cannot
update a `KTable` directly.

I assume that you read the `KTable` from a topic; for this you update the table by writing to the topic and Kafka Streams will update the table by reading from the topic. A `KTable` that is read from a topic is designed to contain the content of the topic.

Of course, writing to a topic will update the `KTable` not instantly but with some delay (it's an async update). If you need a sync update, you cannot use `KTable` but you can use `.transform()` with an attached state.

Comment: What is preferred way to have lookup and updating table? By using `KTable` or by customized `State Stores`?

Comment: IMHO, there is no preferred way. It depends on the use case and requirements. Pick what suits best. The tradeoffs are explained in the answer -- you need to make your own decision.